# What is wrong with my brute-force approach to proving that $\mathbb R$ as a metric space obeys the triangle inequality?

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

In a self-study of metric spaces, I'm looking at the very basic exercise of proving that $(\mathbb R, |y-x|)$ is a metric space. The sticking point was the triangle inequality. I did manage to validate it as follows:

Since for any $a,b \in \mathbb R: |a| + |b| \ge |a+b|$:

$$|z-x| + |y-z| \ge |z-x+y-z| = |y-x|.$$

Therefore, $$|y-x| \le |z-x| + |y-z|,$$ *i.e.* $$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y).$$

So that seems just fine to me, but I still don't understand why my original approach didn't pan out at all. I attempted a brute force expansion of the absolute values in the triangle inequality, assuming that each one could contain a positive or negative value, as follows in a quasi-tabular format:

```
(y-x) (z-x) (y-z)
>=0   >=0   >=0  y-x <= z-x + y-z; 0 <= 0  (um, okay, but suspicious?)
>=0   >=0   <=0  y-x <= z-x + z-y; 2y <= 2z; y <= z (good, since y-z<=0)
>=0   <=0   >=0  y-x <= x-z + y-z; 2z <= 2x; z <= x (good, since z-x<=0)
>=0   <=0   <=0  y-x <= x-z + z-y; 2y <= 2x; y <= x (bad, since y-x>=0!!)
<=0   >=0   >=0  x-y <= z-x + y-z; 2x <= 2y; x <= y (bad, since y-x<=0!!)
<=0   >=0   <=0  x-y <= z-x + z-y; 2x <= 2z; x <= z (good, since z-x>=0)
<=0   <=0   >=0  x-y <= x-z + y-z; 2z <= 2y; z <= y (good, since y-z>=0)
<=0   <=0   <=0  x-y <= x-z + z-y; 0 <= 0 (again okay, but suspicious?)
```

The first and last cases seem suspicious to me because they don't force me to check against the givens for the row, as the others do. But worse, the fourth and fifth cases completely fail. I guess this conceptualization of the proof is just dead wrong, but can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from coincidences, there are only $3!=6$ possible linear ordering among $3$ objects. So your table only needs $6$ rows to deal with all non-trivial cases. If you have $8$ rows, it is reasonable to expect that $8-6=2$ of the rows will be somehow degenerate.

More specifically, if $y-x\geq0$ and $z-x\leq 0$ and $y-z\leq0$, then $y\geq x\geq z\geq y$, which means $x=y=z$. And in this case, it is indeed true that $y\leq x$! So that's not a failure at all.

As for the suspicious rows, well, the triangle inequality is not always a strict inequality.

Comment: Ah! Thank you @ChrisCulter for not only dispelling my beginner's quandary, but also putting an arrow in my quiver: instead of just thinking about positive-negative values inside multiple absolute values, think of the max number of possible orderings (n!) and use ordering to categorize the problem space. This is perfect.